# Is there a way to check push notification setting is ever requested?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Is there a way to check app has ever acquired push notification permission by system alert?

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.types.rawValue`

It returns `0` both when app never requested push notification permission and when user declined permission.

I want to show the system alert popup when app never requested permission. Also I want to let user go to setting to control permission setting if user ever declined permission.

For example:

```
let pushNotificationPermissionNeverAcquired: Bool = ???
if (pushNotificationPermissionNeverAcquired) {
    // show system popup to acquire push notification permission
    UIApplication.sharedApplication.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([ * some types ])

} else if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.types.rawValue == 0) {
    // user declined push notification permission, so let user go to setting and change the permission
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString))

} else {
    // push notification is allowed

}
```

How can I check `pushNotificationPermissionNeverAcquired`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am doing it right now.

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey(NOTIFICATION_PERMISSIONS_ASKED) == nil
    { 
       NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("true", forKey: NOTIFICATION_PERMISSIONS_ASKED)
       // Request permissions
    }
    else
    {
      // Show your own alert 
    }
```

You could save a Boolean too if you want and access it with 'boolForKey', it returns false if no key was found.

Forgot this as well.

```
if let enabledTypes = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()?.types { 
    switch enabledTypes
   {
    case UIUserNotificationType.None:
        // Denied permissions or never given
    default:
        // Accepted
    }
}
```

Comment: It is possible idea but I need to adopt it to a app which is already released. There will be users which allowed/disallowed push notification but don't have that saved value.

Comment: How about requesting for permissions, then checking if your current view controller is presenting an alert controller? (The system one with don't allow/allow). I'm not sure if it would be part of your view hierarchy though.